# Table layout with buttons - Background size of 1st button(1x1) is appearing different in screen than other buttons (using same image for all)

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-tablelayout

I am creating a numeric pad using table layout with buttons as shown in attached images and using a `selector.xml` for setting different background when the buttons are focused or pressed.The first button is taking the default focus, the background image size of the first button(Image 1) is comparatively bigger than the other buttons(Image 2) though I am using the same `selector.xml` for all the buttons in the table layout.
Logically all the buttons should have the same background image as I am using the same `selector.xml`. I have spent quite good in identifying the cause for it but no luck.

I have tried keeping the different image as background even then the same is happening. I tried increasing the table layout rows and column even then the first button's background-size is different.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASr87.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmGCD.png]

**Selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unfocused_button" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/focused_button" android:state_focused="true"></item>
</selector>
```

**Resource file**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/numericPad"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                    <!--android:shrinkColumns="*"
                    android:stretchColumns="*"-->
                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/number_button_selector"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/button1"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"></Button>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/number_button_selector"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"></Button>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/number_button_selector"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"></Button>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button4"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/number_button_selector"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@id/button4"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"></Button>
                    </TableRow>

                    ....Similar code for row 2 and row 3
```

Appreciate your help greatly.

Hope you can understand the issue from my description. If not please let me know in comments, I can give additional details.

Comment: Just helped you visualise your images.

Comment: So kind of you @shizhen. I hope from the image my issue can be understood well.

Comment: @shizhen I have solved the issue and updated the answer. Could you please help me to visualize the updated images in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have solved this issue by keeping a constant height value for all the buttons rather than 'wrap_content'. Now all the button's background are of same.
Thanks for those who have viewed and tried solution for it.
Updated Code:
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/numericPad"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`enter code here`
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
                    <!--android:shrinkColumns="*"
                    android:stretchColumns="*"-->
                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:alpha="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/number_button_selector"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/button1"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"></Button>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/number_button_selector"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"></Button>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/number_button_selector"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"></Button>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button4"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/number_button_selector"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@id/button4"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="20dp"></Button>
                    </TableRow>

[Button 1 with background][1]


[Button 2 with background][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQaBg.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRN6E.png
```